# File I/O in a Linux kernel module

Tags: file-io, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm writing a Linux kernel module that needs to open and read files. What's the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read/write files within a Linux kernel module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184274/how-to-read-write-files-within-a-linux-kernel-module)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Can I ask why are you trying to open a file?

I like to follow Linux development (out of curiosity, I'm not a kernel developer, I do Java), and I've seen discussion of this question before. I was able to find a [LKML message](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0005.3/0061.html) about this, basically mentioning it's usually a bad idea. I'm almost positive that LWN covered it in the last year, but I'm having trouble finding the article.

If this is a private module (like for some custom hardware and the module won't be distributed) then you can do this, but I'm under the impression that if you are going to submit your code to the mainline then it may not be accepted.

Evan Teran mentioned sysfs, which seems like a good idea to me. If you really need to do harder custom stuff you could always make new ioctrls.

EDIT:

OK, I found the article I was looking for, it's from [Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8110). It explains why doing this kind of stuff is generally a bad idea, then goes on to tell you exactly how to do it anyway.

Comment: It's a custom module, it won't be distributed. I need to open a file that contains a mapping of inodes => checksums.

Comment: @mipadi: I found the article I was thinking of, it explains exactly how to open and read a file from the kernel (after the "don't do this" part). I've edited my post to reflect that and contain the link. Good luck.

Answer (score 9):

assuming you can get pointers to the relavent function pointers to the `open`/`read`/`close` system calls, you can do something like this:

```
mm_segment_t fs = get_fs();
set_fs(KERNEL_DS);

fd = (*syscall_open)(file, flags, mode);
if(fd != -1) {
    (*syscall_read)(fd, buf, size);
    (*syscall_close)(fd);
}
set_fs(fs);
```

you will need to create the "`syscall_*`" function pointers I have shown though. I am sure there is a better way, but I believe that this would work.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, if you need to read/write files from a kernel module, you're doing something wrong architecturally.

There exist mechanisms (netlink for example - or just register a character device) to allow a kernel module to talk to a userspace helper process. That userspace helper process can do whatever it wants.

You could also implement a system call (or such like) to take a file descriptor opened in userspace and read/write it from the kernel.

This would probably be neater than trying to open files in kernel space.

There are some other things which already open files from kernel space, you could look at them (the loop driver springs to mind?).

Comment: I've actually altered the mechanism to read from a file in /proc, so I probably won't need to read a file directly.

Answer (score 3):

/proc filesystem is also good for private use, and it's easy.
http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/Linux_Kernel_Module_Programming_Guide/x773.html

Answer (score 3):

All of the kernel developers say that file I/O from kernel space is bad (especially if you're referring to these files by their paths) but the mainstream kernel does this when you load firmware. If you just need to read from files, use the

```
kernel_read_file_from_path(const char *path, void **buf, loff_t *size, loff_t max_size, enum kernel_read_file_id id)
```

function, which is what the firmware loader code uses, declared in `include/linux/fs.h`. This function returns a negative value on error.

I'm not really sure of the point of the `id` variable at the end, if you look at the code it's not really used, so just put something like `READING_FIRMWARE` there (no quotes).

`buf` is not null terminated, instead refer to its size in `size`. If you need it to be null terminated, create a string `size + 1` bytes long and copy it over or rewrite the `kernel_read_file()` function (used by `kernel_read_file_from_path()`, defined in `fs/exec.c`) and add one to `i_size` where memory is allocated. (If you want to do this, you can redefine the `kernel_read_file()` function in your module with a different function name to avoid modifying the whole kernel.)

If you need to write to files, there is a `kernel_write()` function (analogous to `kernel_read()`, which is used by `kernel_read_file()` and therefore also  by `kernel_read_file_from_path()`), but there is no `kernel_write_file()` or `kernel_write_file_from_path()` function. You can look at the code in the `fs/exec.c` file in the Linux kernel source tree where `kernel_read_file()` and `kernel_read_file_from_path()` are defined to write your own `kernel_write_file()` and `kernel_write_file_from_path()` functions that you can include in your module.

And as always, you can store a file's contents in a char pointer instead of a void pointer with this function by casting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also find some informations about sys_call_open in this [Linux Kernel Module Programing Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html#AEN976).

Comment: Yeah, I've taken a look at that. Incidentally, I _am_ patching the open(2) system call, and I actually need to read a file _inside_ my patched version.