# How to get readable pwd in kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, hook

I want to get the current directory, here is my attempt

```
asmlinkage ssize_t fake_read(int __fd, void *__buf, size_t __nbytes){

    struct path pwd;
    get_fs_pwd(current->fs,&pwd);
    char x[1000];
    dentry_path_raw(pwd.dentry,x,999);
    fm_alert("read:%s\n",x);
    return real_read(__fd,__buf,__nbytes);
}
```

However, the output I get is like

```
[ 2170.293439] fsmonko.fake_read: read:ػ\xffffffaf\xffffff80
[ 2170.293466] fsmonko.fake_read: read:ػ\xffffffaf\xffffff80
[ 2170.293483] fsmonko.fake_read: read:\xffffffd8;\xffffff9b\xffffff84
[ 2170.293500] fsmonko.fake_read: read:ػ\xffffffaf\xffffff80
[ 2170.293524] fsmonko.fake_read: read:ػ\xffffffaf\xffffff80
[ 2170.293550] fsmonko.fake_read: read:ػ\xffffffaf\xffffff80
[ 2170.293556] fsmonko.fake_read: read:\xffffffd8;\xffffff9b\xffffff84
```

It's supposed to print the readable pwd, what's wrong?

My kernel version is `4.13.0-36-generic` Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You really want to avoid putting in magical constants like `1000` and `999` and instead use some kind of kernel-defined "max length" constant instead like `PATH_MAX`.

Comment: @tadman thanks, but the output is still the same

Comment: That doesn't fix your problem, but it'll avoid a kernel explosion when you hit a path that's too long for your buffer but allowed by Linux.

Comment: Maybe check return value? `char *p = dentry_path_raw(..);  if (IS_ERR(p)) printk("It failed; errno %ld\n", -PTR_ERR(p));`

Comment: Is your question related [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405842/current-directory-of-a-process-in-linux-kernel)?

Comment: @GilHamilton I've changed to `char *p = dentry_path_raw(pwd.dentry,x,PATH_MAX-1);
    if (IS_ERR(p))
        fm_alert("It failed; errno %ld\n",-PTR_ERR(p));
    else
        fm_alert("read:%s\n",x);` . But it seems no error and the output is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dentry_path_raw` places the path at the end of the buffer. The beginning of the buffer (which you are printing) still contains garbage. An actual start of the path is the value `dentry_path_raw` returns. Try

```
    char * path = dentry_path_raw(pwd.dentry,x,999);
    fm_alert("read:%s\n", path);
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually works. But I'm still confused about the connection between the length of `buffer` and `buflen` in  `path = dentry_path_raw(dentry, buffer, buflen);`

Comment: @user6456568 The `buflen` parameter tells `dentry_path_raw` how much memory it has to its disposal. Unless you have something weird in mind, just pass the actual size of the `buffer`.