# An example of getting the current direcory in kernel code

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366559/getting-current-working-directory-within-kernel-code) shows us how the current working directory in kernel code. I tried to implement this in my module but without success, I really need someone to share with me a **full program** with the answer above. Because I really don't know how to use the answer above and how implement it.

**I tried the following:**

which struct do I need to use in the `get_fs_pwd` function, and what is the `pwd` argument? The answer didn't provide an example of how to really get the `cwd`.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/fs_struct.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, World\n");
    get_fs_pwd(); // which struct do I need to use, and what is the pwd argument?
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, cruel world.\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

```
static inline void get_fs_pwd(struct fs_struct *fs, struct path *pwd)
{
    spin_lock(&fs->lock);
    *pwd = fs->pwd;
    path_get(pwd);
    spin_unlock(&fs->lock);
}
```

Comment: What would be the meaning of the "current directory" in the context of kernel module?

Comment: @EugeneSh. As it sounds, the current directory of my current user. Just like the `pwd` command.

Comment: @DuduFaruk Can't your user have multiple terminals opened with different current directories? Or you mean the directory from which your kernel module was `insmod`ed?

Comment: Current directory is process-specific.  The linked answer is for getting the pwd of the calling process.  In _init I suppose it would be the current directory of the insmod process.  Dependng on the implementation of insmod, it may be under /lib/modules/... at that point.

Comment: @red0ct @ stark I want to get the current working directory of the current process running, from which the module was insert into the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

The following kernel code is an example of `get_fs_pwd` function. Using `dmesg` command, you will see the directory where the kernel module was `insmod`ed, actually **the current working directory of `insmod` process**.

As defined in [`get_fs_pwd`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10/source/include/linux/fs_struct.h#L34), you need to initialize a variable of [`struct path`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10/source/include/linux/path.h#L7), which stores the result extracted from `struct fs_struct`. Here is [`current->fs`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1209), the filesystem information of current process.

As defined in [`d_path`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10/source/fs/dcache.c#L2677), you need to `kmalloc` a string buffer, by which the actual path name can be extracted from `struct path`. Don't forget to `kfree` the buffer after use.

```
#include <linux/dcache.h>
#include <linux/fs_struct.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/limits.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int __init hello_init(void) {
    struct path pwd;
    char *cwd = NULL;
    char *buf = NULL;

    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello World\n");
    get_fs_pwd(current->fs, &pwd);
    buf = kmalloc(PATH_MAX, GFP_ATOMIC | __GFP_NOWARN | __GFP_ZERO);
    if (buf) {
        cwd = d_path(&pwd, buf, PATH_MAX);
        printk(KERN_ALERT "The current working directory: %s\n", cwd);
        kfree(buf);
    }

    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye World\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

If the kernel code is saved as `hello.c`, the following `Makefile` is for your reference.

```
obj-m += hello.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```