# Is there a C function like sprintf in the Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, printf

Is there function like `sprintf()` in Linux Kernel (like `printf()`->`printk()`)?

Comment: Note that for many use cases, the [seq_file](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/seq_file.txt) interface is much better suited. (If you use the `seq_path()` or `seq_escape()` facilities, do remember to include `\` in the set of `escape`'d characters. I've tried to push related bugfixes (in e.g. `/proc`) but getting such "corner cases" any kind of recognition is too much of a problem, so if you introduce such bugs, you are likely going to just have to live with them forever.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

yes. 
https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/lib/vsprintf.c#n1828

```
int snprintf(char *buf, size_t size, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    int i;

    va_start(args, fmt);
    i = vsnprintf(buf, size, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    return i;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(snprintf);
```

`sprintf()` by itself is prone to buffer overflows. <sup>[CERT buffer overflows](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/STR31-C.+Guarantee+that+storage+for+strings+has+sufficient+space+for+character+data+and+the+null+terminator), [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/securecodingguide/Articles/BufferOverflows.html), etc</sup>

Comment: Which header should I include?

Comment: this `http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.5.3/include/linux/kernel.h#L323` located in `linux/include/linux/kernel.h`

Comment: The implementation of this and of some other useful functions (`scnptintf`, `snprintf`, etc.) as well as their description is in [lib/vsprintf.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/vsprintf.c). There are some useful features these functions have that their user-space counterparts do not (`%pS`, for example).

Comment: This answer is wrong. The code referred to above is not built into the kernel. The version of sprintf() available in the kernel is in lib/vsprintf.c I edited the answer but it was rejected by someone who doesn't know what they're talking about.

Comment: Can you extend your answer to mention options like `kasfprintf()`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just include linux/kernel.h

Answer (score 0):

yes there is check out [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/s390/net/ctcm_sysfs.c?v=2.6.32#L30) for example

you can use grep to see if it is in the kernel's source code

Answer (score 0):

Running crash on a live 2.6 kernel confirms sprintf() is defined, and where it is defined.

crash> sym sprintf

ffffffff81267ba0 (T) sprintf ../debug/kernel-2.6.39/linux-2.6.39-400.210.2.el6uek/lib/vsprintf.c: 1442

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf()` is unsafe because of buffer overflow.
If you need to pass data from user space to kernel space, use instead `copy_from_user()`; it acts like `copy_to_user()` but in reverse direction.