# error: stdio.h: No such file or directory error during make

Tags: c, ubuntu, gnu-make

I'm trying to compile the following program in Ubuntu. But I keep getting the error: "stdio.h: No such file or directory" error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello world");
}
```

My makefile is:

```
obj-m += hello.o 
all:
    make -I/usr/include -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Is that a valid way to include things? Try `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: Can you compile without make? e.g. `gcc -o hello hello.c`?

Comment: Are you trying to build a linux kernel module, or just a user space application?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to build for a linux kernel module.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your way of building your program is the way to build kernel module and not c program application. and `stdio.h` does not exist in the environment of the kernel development so that's why you get the error:

```
error: "stdio.h: No such file or directory" error
```

1) If you want to build a linux application then your Makefile is wrong:

You should modify your Makefile

Use the following Makefile:

```
all: hello

test: test.c
    gcc -o hello hello.c

clean:
    rm -r *.o hello
```

2) If you want to build a kernel module then your c code is wrong

- **YOU CAN NOT** use `stdio.h` in the kernel space development.  Itdoes not
  exist in the environment of the kernel development so that's why you
  get the error
- **YOU CAN NOT** use `main()` in the kernel module C code
- **YOU CAN NOT** use `printf()` in the kernel module C code

**INSTEAD** of using `stdio.h`, you have to use the following include

```
#include <linux/module.h>   /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
```

**INSTEAD** of using `int main() {`, you have to use

```
int init_module(void) {
```

**INSTEAD** of using  `printf()` use `printk()`

Use the following [hello module](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x121.html) instead of your hello code

```
/*  
 *  hello-1.c - The simplest kernel module.
 */
#include <linux/module.h>   /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* Needed for KERN_INFO */

int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world 1.\n");

    /* 
     * A non 0 return means init_module failed; module can't be loaded. 
     */
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
```

Please refer to the following [link](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/index.html) for more detail about kernel module development

Comment: You're making an assumption about what the end goal is.

Comment: @Mike looking to the c code. the c code is a code for an application and not for module because it contains the `main()` so that's why I assume that the user has write a wrong makefile

Comment: @Mike. but according to his last comment he want to build a kernel module and not linux application

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you can't use `printf()` and `stdio.h` inside the kernel, and you don't use a `main()` function either. You need `printk()` and `module.h`

```
#include <linux/module.h> /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>

int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world\n");

    return 0;
}
```

You should also have a `exit()`/`cleanup()` type function for when it unloads.

```
void clean_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Cleaning and exiting\n");
}
```

Then load the functions for the module:

```
module_init(init_module);
module_exit(clean_module);
```

Comment: @lash - See [here for a simular question that might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264291/c-sprintf-in-linux-kernel), in general, you can't use any user space library functions in kernel (no stdio.h, stdlib.h, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Your Makefile isn't correct, please take a look at one of the many tutorials, for example: http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

the simplest Makefile to build a standalone application should look something like that:

```
all: hello

hello: hello.o
    gcc hello.o -o hello

hello.o: hello.cpp
    gcc -c hello.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *o hello
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: You're making an assumption about what the end goal is.