# makefile for a libusb program

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel, libusb

I have made a C program using libusb and I am using following command to compile it:

```
gcc -o usbtest.o usbtest.c -lusb-1.0
```

The program is working fine. Next, I added the code of "usbtest.c" to kernel module (usbmod.c) and I am stuck with the make file. I am not sure what command I should pass in the "all" section. Here is what I have made:

```
obj-m := usbmod.o

KERNEL_DIR = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD = $(shell pwd)

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.order *-
```

After running make, I am getting the following error:

```
anubhav@anubhav-Inspiron-3421:~/Desktop/usb$ make
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-46-generic/build     SUBDIRS=/home/anubhav/Desktop/usb modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-46-generic'
CC [M]  /home/anubhav/Desktop/usb/usbmod.o
/home/anubhav/Desktop/usb/usbmod.c:3:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such  file or directory
#include <stdio.h>
               ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/home/anubhav/Desktop/usb/usbmod.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/anubhav/Desktop/usb] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-46-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Not sure if need to bring any header file to my working directory or what. Kindly provide suggestions.

Comment: You don't change `all` at all.  As I understand it, you just add the new `usbtest.o` to the `obj-m` variable assignment.

Comment: @MadScientist The file "usbtest.c" is just a normal c program. I only mentioned it because there was something extra in compilation other than source and object file. While the file "usbmod.c" is a kernel module program for which I want generate object files through make. So I must be using "usbmod.o", isn't it. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Do you have a `stdio.h` file on your system?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes I do. I used "stdio", "stdlib" and "libusb-1.0/libusb.h" in "usbtest.c" and the program is working.

Comment: Using `stdio` is a c++ include directive not a C include directive but ok. Can you get the kernel build to run in verbose mode so you can see the command it is running that is failing?

Comment: @EtanReisner I am sorry to say but I have no knowledge about "Verbose mode". My doubt is how to incorporate the header files I have used in my make file. Should "-lusb-1.0" in the gcc command bring any change to the make file of my kernel module.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Miline I am basically trying to add my own functionality to linux kernel. After going through some posts here, I came to know that any header file that exists in user space can't be used in kernel module. If you can suggest any functionality that can be added without depending on user space header files.

Comment: Voting to close as "too broad", since you have not identified any specific functional goal people can help you with, but are rather just searching for ideas.  Alternately, you can accept the answer that says you can't use libusb in the kernel and leave this question at the trivial tangent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this link clarifies my doubts to some extent:

[][1][error: stdio.h: No such file or directory error during make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662480/error-stdio-h-no-such-file-or-directory-error-during-make)

It says "stdio.h" and all do not exist in kernel space and therefore such errors arise. Besides, obviously my module does not contain any printf so I suppose I don't need "stdio.h".

But it does use libusb extensively. So, is there a way to really create this module.

Comment: This is a rather confused answer (stdio is a lot more than just printf), but if you want to trim it to simply stating that libusb is a userpace library unavailable in the kernel, it could be a good one.  The kernel of course has its own API which drivers use to interact with USB devices.

Comment: okay I understood this thing. Basically I was trying to add a functionality to kernel. Can anyone please suggest any functionality that can be added to the kernel without depending on any user space header files.

Comment: If you want to make a kernel module just to show you can, a hello-world printk is traditional.  Otherwise, figure out what functionality you desire, and then the appropriate kernel interface for doing that - if indeed it is functionality that belongs in the kernel in the first place.  A lot of things that used to *need* to be done there are now believed by many to be preferentially done in user space, and yet others things never belonged in a kernel to begin with.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am already aware of kernel module programming. I am actually in need of a functionality that can be added to kernel. Just an idea. I came up with this idea of simulating lsusb but seems like I took the wrong way. Any suggestions.

Comment: Questions which don't have a specific goal just are not a fit on this site.

Comment: libusb is a library that lets userspace programs talk to USB devices.  You do not have a userspace program.  You will have to figure out what the kernel interfaces are for accessing usb devices, and use those.  In general, you can never use the `-l` option when compiling kernel modules: everything that CAN be called from a kernel module, is already in the kernel!  You can't add libraries like this to your modules, especially not libraries that live in /usr or /lib (these are userspace libraries).