# Conflicting header files in Linux Kernel Module

Tags: c, linux, sockets, linux-kernel

I'm trying to write a Linux kernel module that uses `first_net_device()` from `<linux/netdevice.h>` and `getsockname()` from `<sys/socket.h>`. The problem at compile time is that these two header files have some duplicate definitions, resulting in a compilation failure. How do I solve this? Thanks

Comment: use extern to import one of the functions without including the header

Comment: After that how do I let the linker know where to find the definition of `getsockname()`?

Comment: This is surprising to see there are conflicting names such as this. Maybe not linking with one of the shared libraries and opening it with [`dlopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym) will work.

Comment: `getsockname` is a *user space* function. It cannot be used within *kernel*. Try to find kernel function, which have similar semantic. Including user-space headers for kernel code doesn't work too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why cant we use C function in kernel developement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485271/why-cant-we-use-c-function-in-kernel-developement)

Answer (score 2):

The `sys/socket.h` header is not a kernel header. When you try and add it to your module you'll almost certainly get errors because it's not part of the kernel. Have a look at this answer for more details....

[Why can't we use C standard library functions in kernel development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485271/why-cant-we-use-c-function-in-kernel-developement)