# How can my kernel module access a PCI device without using pci_get_device()?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

At present, I have a Linux 2.6 kernel module which accesses a certain device via `pci_get_device()` and `pci_read_config_dword()`. In future, the module shall be modified to **also** work a different machine which seems to have no PCI bus (/sys/bus/pci doesn't exist), but has the certain device at a fixed, known address. Now, I would like to have **one** module binary **without** parameters which works on both machines. To be able to load the module on the non-PCI machine, I think I must refrain from using `pci_get_device()` etc.; thus I have to get the needed config space info *on the PCI machine* in some other way. I could read it from `/sys/bus/pci/devices/.../resource` in my `init_module()`, but I gather it is considered bad practice to make kernel modules read files. Are there better ways to achieve my goal?

Comment: If you have a PCI device, you have a PCI bus.  So either you're having a different problem (can't find bus, for example), or in the second system your device is not actually connected via PCI, but via some other local bus.  As an aside, `pci_get_device` is not the standard way to write drivers for PCI devices.  Have you read the PCI chapter of "Linux Device Drivers 3"?

Comment: What architecture are you working with?  Does it use device tree files?

Comment: @Peter: Well, I already assumed in my question that the second system has no PCI bus; indeed, the device must be connected via some other bus. The module is not an actual driver for a PCI device, but a pseudo driver that accesses the device memory among other memory regions; therefore, `pci_register_driver()` instead of `pci_get_device()` doesn't suit.
@BenjaminLeinweber: The CPU in both systems is a PowerPC MPC5200. Yes, there are device-trees in both systems.

Comment: @Armali: if the device can be connected with two different busses, you'll need two different code paths to talk to it.  To avoid parameters, just first check for a PCI device, then if it fails, try whatever probe will work for your other bus.  Based on which one succeeds, set a variable in your device struct that indicates how to talk to it, and wrap this decision behind low-level accessor functions.

Comment: Of course, that's basically the way to go. But the core of my question is: _Are there better ways to get the PCI address info than reading `/sys/bus/pci/devices/.../resource`?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When functions like `pci_get_device()` cannot be used (because the module must work also with kernels that don't provide such functions), apparently there is no better way to get the PCI address info than reading `/sys/bus/pci/devices/.../resource`.
I resorted to doing so, using `filp_open()`, `vfs_read()` and `filp_close()` on the basis of [How to read/write files within a Linux kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184274/how-to-read-write-files-within-a-linux-kernel-module).