# Changing kernel variables/parameters from a kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, kernel

There are some kernel variables(for example `tcp_frto`) which can be accessible from the user space by using the commands like `sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_frto` or `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_frto`.

It can be read and easily changed from bash command line. But I want to change them from the kernel module that I am writing.

How can I read and write into these variables from the module?

(Linux source code uses `sysctl_tcp_frto` to access this variable which was declared in the `tcp.h` file. Maybe possible to EXPORT the varible name and then can be found by modules, but I don't want to change the source and compile it again). I am trying to make a Loadable Kernel Module (LKM) without compiling the source every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless a Linux kernel variable is made global (using `EXPORT_SYMBOL` or one of its variants) it cannot be read outside its scope.

As there is an alternate means to access `tcp_frto` using the **procfs**, you can use VFS functions to do the same from within a Linux kernel module as shown in these **[sample code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1184346/319204)**.

How this works and why it is generally NOT a good idea (unless except for debugging) is described in detail in this **[article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/8110/print)**.