# Getting file descriptors and details within kernel space without open()

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Could anyone provide the code to overcome this problem?

Effectively how do we obtain the `struct inode*` from kernel level given the file `/dev/driver1`?

Given in user space that:

```
int fd;
fd = open("/dev/driver1", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
```

In Kernel space:

```
static long dev_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned cmd, unsigned long arg)
struct dev_handle *handle;
handle = file->private_data;
```

Assuming that, we do not go by that path,

How do we obtain within the kernel itself, by eg. hard coding the `file->private_data` to be given to handle?

Comment: Why do you need the file descriptor number? That's not something your filesystem code should need to know.

Comment: I know, but some high ranking guy specified the requirements. No one can change it.

Comment: What are these requirements? This sounds like a XY problem.

Comment: That's the requirement. To imitate the calling but from the kernel domain.

Comment: Get the *high ranking guy* fired. He should not be allowed anywhere near Linux kernels. His *"requirements"* are the exact opposite of how the Linux kernel works. The driver interfaces work on userspace pointers, and won't work with kernel ones; you'd need to construct or simulate a userspace process to be able to call these functions. The obvious intent, considering the glaring stupidity of the approach, is to avoid GPLv2 enforcement, right? Won't work, though: the kernel-userspace boundary is not a copyright law boundary, it's just a technical detail. Just ask your lawyer, okay?

Comment: The above is not to say it's impossible; just idiotic and perverse. If you really need to do this, remember you only need a userspace context (including stack, a bit of memory to hold the data, and so on). You can create a process using code similar to the usermodehelper approach, in [kernel/kmod.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/kmod.c).

Comment: Absolutely agree with the high-ranking issue. 1 of our guys highlighted similar issue, but it was still pushed ahead.

The user space will not be called. Could you show the codes for this? Thank you

Comment: @Babbit: To be honest, I didn't realize using `old_fs=get_fs(); set_fs(KERNEL_DS); DO_STUFF(); set_fs(old_fs);` is a portable way (on non-x86 hardware, I mean) to get around the userspace boundary, but it is. (`__user` is an address space annotation, and `set_fs()` switches between kernel and user address spaces, on all hardware architectures.) Go read what Greg Kroah-Hartman had to say about this approach [in 2005](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/8110). I'd print the LinuxJournal article, and post it on the nearest wall, making sure the title is visible, if I were you.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `filp_open` function. From file `include/linux/fs.h`:

```
struct file *filp_open(const char *filename, int flags, umode_t mode);
```

Here is a link to function source and documentation: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/open.c#L937

If you really need FD, you can use `sys_open` (not exported in newer kernels):

```
long sys_open(const char __user *filename, int flags, int mode);
```

You can find a very good answer on a similar question:
[How to read/write files within a Linux kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184274/how-to-read-write-files-within-a-linux-kernel-module)

Edit (how to get `inode`):

You can get cached `inode` from `struct file`:

```
struct file *file = ...;
struct inode *inode = file->inode;
```

If you want it with locking: here is a background: `Documentation/filesystems/path-lookup.txt`

The starting point for traversing is `current->fs->root`. There is a number of function in kernel, that already do the work, you can find them in `fs/namei.c` source file.

There is a function: `kern_path`:

```
int error;
struct inode *inode;
struct path path;

error = kern_path(pathname, LOOKUP_FOLLOW, &path);
if (error) ...;

inode = path.dentry->d_inode;
```

Comment: This would appear to yield a `struct file*` or an `fd`, and not a `struct inode *` which is what the OP wanted.

Comment: How can we get the `struct inode*`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is in the dev_ioctl function ?
If so, then

```
static long dev_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned cmd, unsigned long arg)
    struct dev_handle *handle;
    struct inode *inode;
    handle = file->private_data;    
    inode = file->f_inode;
```

There seems to be no sane documentation for locking requirements, so you should probably try to dig up similar code and see how it operates on the `f_inode` member.

Comment: No, _ioctl won't be called.