# How can I get an underlying mounted block device which contains a file?

Tags: c, file-io, linux-kernel, kernel-module

So, the problem is: I've got a block device, for example, /dev/sdd1, containing a filesystem, e.g. EXT3 or XFS, mounted under /mnt/testdisk.

There's also a file, /mnt/testdisk/somefile.bin.

What I want, is to get which device that file is on, in this case, "/dev/sdd1". And, to make the matters worse, I have to do it in both userspace and kernel module (It's a linux driver. It doesn't have to be portable).

In userspace:
my current attempt is to open

```
/proc/mounts
```

and parse it line-by-line to find the best match for the pathname. It works, but I think there's must be a better way...

In kernel driver:
I'm trying to open the file, "/mnt/testdisk/somefile.bin", using filp_open from linux/fs.h header.

```
struct file *testfile;
struct inode *inode;
testfile = filp_open("/mnt/testdisk/somefile.bin", (O_RDWR | O_LARGEFILE), OP_FLAGS);
inode = testfile->f_mapping->host;
```

however, for some reason

```
inode->i_bdev == NULL
```

so I can't extract block device path from that :(

I know that theoretically it's a bad thing to open files from kernelspace, but yeah, whatever, don't care.

So, for each case, what's the best way to solve that conundrum?

Comment: I have a similar problem here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/72219414/1569204 with a horrible script as the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72219415/1569204 . There must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right way in the userspace by accessing `/proc/mounts`.

However you can not access userpace directories from kernel space (eg. `/mnt/...`). I suggest you take a look at how the kernel populates `/proc/mount` and use that as a starting point for implementing your functionality.

Take a look at the [kernel source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/proc_namespace.c), that would be `proc_namespace.c` for you. Take a look at the `show_vfsstat` function.

Answer (score 0):

For the userspace portion, I would strace df -h:

```
df -h /mnt/testdisk/somefile.bin
```

And for the kernel portion, you can get the struct block_device by using the following:

```
struct file *testfile;
struct block_device *bdev;

testfile = filp_open("/mnt/testdisk/somefile.bin", (O_RDWR | O_LARGEFILE), OP_FLAGS);
bdev = testfile->f_inode->i_sb->s_bdev;
```

There is also a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002101/getting-file-descriptors-and-details-within-kernel-space-without-open).