# trunc() and ftrunc() equivalent in linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, file-io, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I wanted to know truncate() equivalent function for Linux Kernel Module.
I want to selectively truncate data in a file in kernel module starting from an index and ending at another index.
All suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Avoid doing that in kernel land. Consider [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)

Comment: Why do you think you need to do file operations in kernel code?

Comment: Because I like to play with things..

Answer (score 0):

You would have go one level lower and use Virtual File System level functions. which will allow you to call `truncate` directly.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184274/how-to-read-write-files-within-a-linux-kernel-module) is an example for open/close, read/write in kernel space. You may use the equivalent `vfs_trunc(...)` method

But there are many discussion why you should [NOT](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8110) do that.