# unable to open / read text file from kernel module on linux kernel version 4.2.3

Tags: file, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I have written a kernel module which I'm loading on kernel 4.2.3 . I am trying to read a simple text file in my `init_module` which basically loads some configuration data by reading the contents of the text file. This same code works on previous versions of kernel but not on 4.2.3 Below is my code snippet for reference :

```
struct file* pFile = NULL;
pFile = filp_open(fileName, mode, 0);
if(pFile != NULL){
if(IS_ERR(pFile))
{
  printk("<1>error %p for %s**\n", pFile, fileName);
  pFile = NULL;
}
else if(pFile->f_op->read == NULL || pFile->f_op->write == NULL)
{
  filp_close(pFile, 0);
  pFile = NULL;
}
```

In my case I am getting `pFile->f_op->read` function pointer as `NULL`. This code works fine for non text files like `/proc/kallsyms` which I am able to open & read. Please provide me some pointers as to is this a 4.2.3 kernel specific issue, how can i workaround this in my kernel module code ? Any pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: It's usually bad idea to mess with files in kernel. Why do you need to do that in the first place? Also, I'm encouraging you to stick to [kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) if you are expecting your code to go to the upstream (and frankly I've just skipped reading your code as it's completely unreadable for me).

Comment: yeah i know all that , but what is it in 4.2.3 whats causing this behaviour . Its a pretty simple piece of code and anyone who has dealt with kernel modules should be able to comprehend it easily .

Answer (score 2):

`.read` is not the only interface which can implement reading from file. Files also may use `.read_iter` for that.

For reading a file, instead of direct call to `->read`, use

```
ssize_t vfs_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *pos)
```

which takes into account every possibility.

Similarly, for writing a file

```
ssize_t vfs_write(struct file *file, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *pos)
```

should be used.

**UPDATE**: Since Linux kernel 4.14 for read/write files in the kernel space functions `kernel_read` and `kernel_write` should be used instead. See [that my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53917617/3440745) for more info.

---

**Reading from file to kernel's buffer** (before Linux kernel 4.14)

Because `vfs_read` expects buffer pointed to *user-space memory* (`__user` type attribute denotes that), passing in-kernel buffer will not work: it may cause compiler warning about inconsysency between expected and actual type of second parameter to `vfs_read`, and, more important, `vfs_read` will reject (by returning -EFAULT) buffer as pointed not to user space. But one can overcome this behaviour by changing user-space memory segment:

```
/*
 * Assume that `kernel_buf` points to kernel's memory and has type char*.
 */
char __user *user_buf = (__force char __user *)kernel_buf; // Make compiler happy.
mm_segment_t oldfs = get_fs(); // Store current use-space memory segment.
set_fs(KERNEL_DS); // Set user-space memory segment equal to kernel's one.

vfs_read(file, user_buf, count, pos);

set_fs(oldfs); // Restore user-space memory segment after reading.
```

Comment: What exactly you get with `vfs_read`? Does function call fail with error? Which error code it returns? `vfs_read` is what syscall `read` uses after it resolves file object. So, if `vfs_read` fails, reading file from user-space would likely fail too.

Comment: I m getting error code EFAULT  as return value from vfs_read .

Comment: EFAULT means that `buf` is not allocated by user. You probably use in-kernel buffer, which is not quite correct here. You may try to use `__vfs_read` instead `vfs_read`: it doesn't check buffer using `access_ok`. But nothing prevents `.read` interface of file to perform same check.

Comment: I am using kmalloc (size , GFP_KERNEL ) to allocate buffer where i wish to read the contents of the file . Passing this buffer as the 2nd argument in vfs_read call .

Comment: Thanks a lot ... i  am now able to read contents using vfs_read , I wasnt doing the get_fs() & set_fs() properly which was causing the EFAULT error .

Comment: I added info about `get_fs`/`set_fs` to my post. Probably, it will helps others.