# where can I get man page for `struct file* file_open(const char* path, int flags, int rights)`

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am trying to write a  [module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34307060/error-in-reading-a-file-within-linux-module) to read a file (in kernel mode). 
***However, problem is kernel version 2.6.30 and after does, not export sys_read()***

I have changed code  to

- `struct file* file_open(const char* path, int flags, int rights)` &
- `int file_read(struct file* file, unsigned long long offset, unsigned char* data, unsigned int size)`

to read file.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184274/how-to-read-write-files-within-a-linux-kernel-module) I am having confusion in use of parameters `int rights` in `file_open()` (is it same as `mode` in 'open()').

Please suggest me with an example or help me to get man page for `file_open()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are same.

From [rz2 man pages for FILP_OPEN](http://rz2.com/man9/filp_open.9.html),

> ```
> struct file * filp_open(const char * filename, int flags, int mode);
> ```
>
> ARGUMENTS
>
> - filename: path to open .
> - flags: open flags as per the open(2) second argument.
> - mode: mode for the new file if O_CREAT is set, else ignored.

`file_open` passes its third argument `int rights` as the third argument to `filp_open`, i.e., `int mode`.

`file_open` is defined by you as a wrapper function to underlying VFS level function `filp_open`. So, you can't expect to find a manpage on `file_open`.

Comment: Yes. This answer  cleared  my confusion, and I accepted it. Thank you. :)