# Linux kernel module configuration

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

For my university project I'm doing a module which will allow or disallow a process to perform a system calls (e. g. A little loadable selinux). For now I nave code that controls syscalls. For each process I store a link to the structure which contains permissions config. However, now I've just hardcoded two configs: one is default (allow all) and another one is to allow everything except opening '/testfile'.

My question is how to load configs dynamically?

I have a parser for config files but I've read that accessing files from the kernel is bad idea.

How should I store configs and how should I load them?

Comment: Create a character device and read config lines and directives (i.e. "remove config") from it. A user-space program with sufficient privileges will read a config file from some place in the filesystem and pipe it down to your character device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've read that reading files from the kernel is bad idea

Description of [filp_open](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/open.c?v=4.0#L969) function in the kernel sources says:

> This is the helper to open a file from kernelspace if you really have to. But in generally you should not do this, so please move along, nothing to see here..

So, **if you need** to load/store content of the file into/from the kernel module, **then do that**. But use appropriate functions, as described [in that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1184274/3440745).