# linux kernel: how to remove a file in kernel space

Tags: file, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I know this is strongly **not recommended**. But does is possible to do this in kernel space.

**Given the file path**, can we remove the corresponding file in kernel space?

Comment: Using `call_usermodehelper_fns` to exec `rm`  in kernel space is the way I could think out. The real example in kernel could be found [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/kmod.c#L69), by which kernel calls `/sbin/modprobe` to load module.

Comment: Looks like you look for function [vfs_unlink](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/namei.c#L3785), but its usage is relatively complex. It is called from [do_unlinkat](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/namei.c#L3831) with simple usage, but that function is *static*, so it is inaccessible for you.

Comment: likely similar techniques to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184274/how-to-read-write-files-within-a-linux-kernel-module

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too late, I'll try to reply. As *Tsyvarev* said in his comment probably you are looking for the vfs_unlink function that you can find here [namei.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.15/source/fs/namei.c#L3956).
Before the implementation there is a description, but a simple example can be this one
    /* 
    fcheck's prototype is in linux/fdtable.h and returns a file pointer given a 
    given a file descriptor 
    */

```
struct file *filp= fcheck(fd);
struct inode *parent_inode = filp->f_path.dentry->d_parent->d_inode;
inode_lock(parent_inode);
vfs_unlink(parent_inode, filp->f_path.dentry, NULL);    
inode_unlock(parent_inode);
```

I hope it's can be useful to someone.