# linux kernel programming - create a file or open a file with root permissions

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm creating my own syscalls and
I'm using functions from this link [How to read/write files within a Linux kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184274/how-to-read-write-files-within-a-linux-kernel-module)
to reading and writing to files

the problem is that these functions are not working when non-root user calls my new syscall.

the options are: set root permissions before calling to these functions
or create a file with permission 777 before calling to these functions
maybe there are more options

but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: To set permissions to `777` call `chmod 777 FILENAME`.

Comment: @EliSadoff: Spawning a process from within the kernel just to do that seems like an extremely silly idea. Setting permissions to `777` is usually a silly idea to begin with. It's not a slot machine!

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I was just saying how to set permissions to `777`.

Comment: @EliSadoff: And you would do that in kernel code?

Comment: I generally run `chmod 777` or `chmod +x` on my file in the terminal.

Comment: @EliSadoff: What part of "kernel code" do you not understand? There is no terminal. There is no shell. And what do you even mean by "finals"?

Comment: @MattiViekkunen Check ny answer, which should be a hint at how you can work.

Comment: Consider posting on the sister site Unix/Linux.SE instead, which seems more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow emulate the setfsuid call (without permission checks), perform the open and restore the fsuid of the current process. Changing the FS UID will then allow you to actually call the open syscall, use the file descriptor for yourself (warning: user code will also be capable of using that file descriptor!), then restoring the FS UID reduces the security hole to the file descriptor you are using. It's recommended you also close the file before returning to user space.

Comment: how? how? how? how?

Comment: Well, for emulating the setfsuid call it's actually something I'm messing with myself; I'd take inspiration from the real setfsuid call and simply remove the stuff that conditionally returns -EACCES, then make it set the FS UID to 0.

Comment: I can create fucntion similar to setfsuid, and I have to call my new created fucntion before a call flip_open?

Comment: You call that function, then do the file open (sys_open), then restore the old fsuid.