# How can I write a system call to simulate `cat /proc/stat`?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I want to add a system call to print CPU utilization to stdout. But I find the function "system()" in "stdlib.h" seem can't work in linux kernel? Is there another method to simulate "cat /proc/stat" ?

Comment: have you tried opening the file normally and `printk`ing the contents?

Comment: @ChrisTurner Sorry for this newbie question. How to open a file within system call implementation? I have tried to use filp_open, it pass the compile but the system behave strange after switch to the modified kernel.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this might count as a duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184274/how-to-read-write-files-within-a-linux-kernel-module

Comment: `but printk contents with "dmesg"` - What does this mean? Do you want to prepend content with current time, cpu number and so?

Comment: @ChrisT I want to write a system call, and it can implement `cat /froc/stat`. At the beginning, I try `system("cat /froc/stat")`, but it can't work. Is there another way to do it ?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sorry for my poor English. I have edited it.

Comment: @BoyouYu I already linked to a similar question that describes how to read a file from within the kernel - did that not help?

Comment: @nos I want to write a system call. In `unistd_32.h`, there is `#define__NR_cpu_utilization 337`. then I write a test program. there is a line `syscall(337)` Then, I compile the test program and execute it, it can do the same thing just like typing `cat /froc/stat` in the terminal.

Comment: @ChrisTurner Sorry for reply late. It really helpful. Thx~

Answer (score 1):

You can check how linux kernel populates information in `/proc/stat` file.

Check the implementation of function `show_stat` defined in `fs/proc/stat.c` inside linux kernel source code. You will get some idea.

I hope this will help you.