# How to rename devicenode in char driver

Tags: linux-device-driver, udev

I wrote driver which creates two device nodes as `/dev/dummy1` and `/dev/dummy2`.
created `test.txt` and `cat`test.txt > /dev/dummy1 ,

```
cat /dev/dummy1 & cat /dev/dummy2
```

is fine.

I want to redirect same data to file `/tmp/copy.txt`

How to redirect data form `/dev/dummy1 to /tmp/copy.txt` from char driver itself.(without command line or user application)

Is there any way to rename the device node from `/dev/dummy2` to `/tmp/xxxx` ?
or create the new device node with `/tmp/xxx` and copy `/dev/dummy2` to `/tmp/xxx`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No. Devices are located in `devfs`, period. Your driver does not know neither about `tmpfs` existence, nor about it's mounting point. You are going the wrong direction.

If you want to obtain data from your driver and save it in a custom location, you need to implement a daemon, user-space application that extracts data from driver via `devfs` or `sysfs`, or do the same via command line if you prefer manual approach.

Comment: But my requirement is to do from Char diver itself.If it is from command line, can use mknod()   or  cp  -p /dev/xxxx /tmp/****  or ln  -s  <> <>.

Comment: This requirement is wrong. You should avoid doing this. In any case, it's possible, but you were warned: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1184274/147407