# Regarding filp_open usage in linux kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, linux-scst

Many of the kernel developers suggest that opening a file in the kernel land is not good.

Contrary to this SCST device handler for vdisk is using `filp_open` call.

How is this accepted by the Linux kernel community?

Comment: `How is this accepted by the Linux kernel community?` - Whose **opinion** you want to hear? Linus Torvalds's one? One of the top maintainer's? "Linux kernel community" is very large, and every its member has own thoughts. Several posts on Stack Overflow, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1184346/3440745), suggests that one may access files from the kernel if he **really needs** that. Some sorts of drivers cannot work without accessing files.

Comment: Even the post you are referring mentions -- "You should be aware that that you should avoid file I/O when possible." -- I am seeking general opinion of Linux kernel developers on file I/O in the kernel space. If that opinion (to avoid file I/O in kernel space) has any change since then when the article was first written/published by Greg Kroah-Hartman "http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/8110/print" -- for the benefit of Linux kernel new enthusiasts provide as much insight as possible on why generally file I/O in kernel considered bad.