# How to 'sys_seek' in terms of 'sys_read'?

Tags: linux, file, io, kernel, system-calls

File handling in a kernel module. What is the appropriate way to 'seek' in a file? I could not find a `sys_seek()` function (such as `sys_read()`). Or, is it better only to use the VFS function API?

The question [How to read/write files within a Linux kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184274/how-to-read-write-files-within-a-linux-kernel-module) does not handle input stream navigation, i.e. there is no reference to `tell()/seek()` of any kind.

Comment: did you look at lseek? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html

Comment: Can you use lseek in kernel space?

Comment: syscalls.h has sys_lseek. `long sys_lseek(unsigned int fd, off_t offset,
     unsigned int whence);` I believe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read/write files within a Linux kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184274/how-to-read-write-files-within-a-linux-kernel-module)

Comment: @Simonare: Thanks, I did not find documentation on that but the signature seems intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seek` functionality in the kernel space can be achieved by `vfs_llseek` function:

```
loff_t vfs_llseek(struct file *file, loff_t offset, int whence);
```

The function returns resulted offset or negative value in case of error.

Comment: I would feel bad to use APIs of different levels of abstraction.

Comment: `vfs_llseek` has the same "level of abstraction" as a function `vfs_write`, noted in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1184346/3440745) to the question referenced by yours. If you compare with `sys_read` instead... then symply do not use `sys_*` functions (syscalls) in the kernel: syscalls are primarily for user-space applications.

Comment: So, I guess you want to say that my assumption that kernel modules better rely on the VFS functions instead of syscalls is correct?

Comment: Yes, `vfs_` prefixed functions are better for the Linux kernel programming than `sys_` ones. E.g. file-related syscalls work with a **file descriptor** (`int fd`), but kernel itself mostly uses an object of type `struct file*`. Even if you have a *file descriptor* as input, then you may use [ksys_lseek](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.16/source/fs/read_write.c#L304).