# android kernel read file

Tags: android, c++, c, kernel

I am building a custom Android os by inserting some my own code into Android OS code file "/art/runtime/art_method.cc". In my code, I want to read a text file by calling the following read file function:

```
FILE* f = fopen(file_name,"r");
```

However, I find that the inserted code cannot read the text file when the Android OS is running.

The version of Android OS source code is android-8.1.0_r40

I read a post in stack overflow: [Read/write files within a Linux kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184274/read-write-files-within-a-linux-kernel-module/1184346#1184346) 
but it is related to the Linux kernel but not the android kernel. There are no C head files in the accepted answer for Android OS source code.

So, I want to know how to read the file in the Android kernel.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I have deleted my post as it did not add anything new to what you already know.  But, it is important to note:  1) File I/O in the way you are proposing is highly discouraged from within Linux. (This would include the Android variant of Linux.)   2) Android OS, although based on a highly customized variant of Linux, is not Linux.  If you choose to go against recommendations _not_ to do File I/O, then find the API/methods that are provided within the Android OS environment, and do not be surprised that _regular_ Linux API calls are not provided.