# Unknown symbol vfs_write (err -2) in kernel module in kernel 4.20

Tags: c, file-io, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to set a keylogger kernel module. all is fine except the final log file. I'm trying to, at the exit of the module, write a log in a /tmp/ file.

I'm using last kernel version 4.20. I'm trying to use vfs_write, but when compiling, it tells me

> "WARNING : vfs_write [...] undefined !"

and when im trying to insert the module it says me

> "Unknown symbol vfs_write (err -2)"

i am using this method to do the job: [Read/write files within a Linux kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184274/read-write-files-within-a-linux-kernel-module)

Tell me What i did wrong or how to correctly open /to write a file x).
Thanks for all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 4.14 of Linux kernel, `vfs_write` function is **no longer exported** for use in modules. Use `kernel_write` instead. It has the the same signature:

```
ssize_t kernel_write(struct file *file, const void *buf, size_t count,
            loff_t *pos)
```

Comment: I just found it yes ! Thanks for this issue !