# Linux VFS: vfs_read(..., &offset) vs. vfs_llseek(..., pos): How to seek in a file from kernel module

Tags: c, file-io, linux-kernel, vfs

**GIVEN**:

in `fs/read_write.c` the function `vfs_read()` has a signature as shown bewlow:

```
 ssize_t vfs_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *pos)
```

where the last argument is a pointer to a position. The signature itself is not documented. The signature, I would think, insinuates that the initial read position is passed to the read function, and maybe the updated position (next position to be read from) is written in `*pos`. Then, however, there is the function `vfs_llseek()` in `fs/read_write.c` with the signature

```
loff_t vfs_llseek(struct file *file, loff_t offset, int whence)
```

which looks like a 'normal' seek function. Also, the signature is not documented along side with the code.

**QUESTIONS**:

1. How does one actually seek in a file using VFS?
2. Is the *position* equal to the index of the byte in the file, i.e. first byte position = 0, position = position + 1 for subsequent bytes?

Comment: This question is also relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184274/read-write-files-within-a-linux-kernel-module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does one actually seek in a file using VFS?

Using `vfs_llseek` is correct for this purpose.

VFS actually has a notion about *current file's position*, which is stored in the `file->f_pos` field. Successful call for `vfs_llseek` updates this position. But for use this position when read the file, you need explicitly pass the value of the field via `pos` parameter of the `vfs_read` and, upon successful return, write resulted value of that parameter back to the field:

```
loff_t pos = file->f_pos;
ssize_t res = vfs_read(file, buf, count, &pos);
if (res > 0) {
  file->f_pos = pos;
}
```

Existed signature of `vfs_read` allows to use this function both in normal `read` syscall and in `pread` syscall, which uses user-specified position instead of the current one.

> Is the position equal to the index of the byte in the file, i.e. first byte position = 0, position = position + 1 for subsequent bytes?

This is true for **regular** files, which are stored on a hard drive or other media.

For special files, like ones located under `/sys` or `/dev`, meaning of the position could be *any* (that is, it is defined by the file). E.g., if a file exposes information as an array of records, position could mean the index of the record, not the index of the byte.