# filp_open crashes in release function of char device driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a device driver, and I need to do many operations when a file is closed, and one of these operations is opening another file. Everything works perfectly if the user runs open, close and return. But if the user only runs open and then returns, my driver crashes, and I've noticed that it crashes just when it tries to do the filp_open in my release function.
I had the impression that when the release function is invoked not directly by the user (via a close) but directly by the kernel (because the user makes a return without the close), I can't do a filp_open. (Obviously the path is always correct, because it works when the user try to do open, close and return in this order).

This is the code that causes the crash during my releases method:

```
struct file *file_open(const char *path, int flags, int rights)
{
    if(path==NULL){
        print_message("path is NULL\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    struct file *filp = NULL;
    mm_segment_t oldfs;
    int err = 0;

    oldfs = get_fs();
    set_fs(get_ds());
    print_message("I'm doing filp_open");

    filp = filp_open(path, flags, rights);
    set_fs(oldfs);
    if (IS_ERR(filp)) {
        print_message("error during filp_open\n");
        err = PTR_ERR(filp);
        return NULL;
    }
    if(filp==NULL){
        print_message("filp is NULL\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    return filp;
}
```

and this is the dump of the kernel when I execute dmesg:

```
[  961.870540] I'm doing filp_open
[  961.870548] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000008
[  961.870550] PGD 0 P4D 0
[  961.870554] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
[  961.870556] CPU: 1 PID: 2315 Comm: userspace Tainted: G           OE     4.18.0-25-generic #26~18.04.1-Ubuntu
[  961.870558] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
[  961.870570] RIP: 0010:set_root+0x26/0xc0
[  961.870571] Code: 1f 44 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 65 48 8b 04 25 00 5c 01 00 48 89 e5 41 55 41 54 41 52 53 f6 47 38 40 4c 8b a0 88 0a 00 00 74 3d <41> 8b 4c 24 08 f6 c1 01 75 7c 49 8b 54 24 20 49 8b 44 24 18 48 89
[  961.870596] RSP: 0018:ffffbd9bc33dbaa8 EFLAGS: 00010202
[  961.870598] RAX: ffff9a8f72384500 RBX: ffffbd9bc33dbbf0 RCX: 0000000000000001
[  961.870599] RDX: ffffffff8fef34c8 RSI: 0000000000000041 RDI: ffffbd9bc33dbbf0
[  961.870600] RBP: ffffbd9bc33dbac8 R08: ffff9a8fbfd27080 R09: ffff9a8fb474c600
[  961.870602] R10: ffffbd9bc33dba98 R11: 00000000ffffffff R12: 0000000000000000
[  961.870603] R13: ffffbd9bc33dbbf0 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: 0000000000000002
[  961.870605] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9a8fbfd00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  961.870606] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  961.870607] CR2: 0000000000000008 CR3: 0000000050e0a002 CR4: 00000000000606e0
[  961.870610] Call Trace:
[  961.870615]  path_init+0x16f/0x2f0
[  961.870617]  path_openat+0x78/0x1780
[  961.870621]  ? sched_clock+0x9/0x10
[  961.870626]  ? sched_clock_cpu+0x11/0xb0
[  961.870628]  do_filp_open+0x9b/0x110
[  961.870633]  ? vprintk_emit+0xec/0x290
[  961.870636]  file_open_name+0x114/0x180
[  961.870638]  ? file_open_name+0x114/0x180
[  961.870640]  filp_open+0x33/0x60
[  961.870643]  file_open+0x56/0x90 [driver]
[  961.870645]  my_char_device_driver_close+0x96/0x190 [driver]
[  961.870647]  __fput+0xea/0x220
[  961.870649]  ____fput+0xe/0x10
[  961.870652]  task_work_run+0x9d/0xc0
[  961.870655]  do_exit+0x2eb/0xb30
[  961.870658]  ? __do_page_fault+0x270/0x4d0
[  961.870660]  do_group_exit+0x43/0xb0
[  961.870662]  __x64_sys_exit_group+0x18/0x20
[  961.870666]  do_syscall_64+0x5a/0x120
[  961.870672]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
[  961.870674] RIP: 0033:0x7f0304ee3e06
[  961.870675] Code: Bad RIP value.
[  961.870679] RSP: 002b:00007fff99afb5c8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000e7
[  961.870680] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007f03051e6740 RCX: 00007f0304ee3e06
[  961.870682] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 000000000000003c RDI: 0000000000000000
[  961.870686] RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 00000000000000e7 R09: ffffffffffffff80
[  961.870688] R10: 0000000000000002 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00007f03051e6740
[  961.870689] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: 00007f03051ef628 R15: 0000000000000000
[  961.870691] Modules linked in: driver(OE) vboxvideo(OE) vboxsf(OE) snd_intel8x0 snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event ghash_clmulni_intel joydev pcbc snd_rawmidi aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper snd_seq intel_rapl_perf input_leds snd_seq_device snd_timer serio_raw snd soundcore mac_hid vboxguest(OE) sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse video vmwgfx ttm ahci drm_kms_helper libahci syscopyarea e1000 sysfillrect i2c_piix4 sysimgblt fb_sys_fops pata_acpi drm
[  961.870724] CR2: 0000000000000008
[  961.870726] ---[ end trace 3fb99e3beca99ccc ]---
[  961.870728] RIP: 0010:set_root+0x26/0xc0
[  961.870729] Code: 1f 44 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 65 48 8b 04 25 00 5c 01 00 48 89 e5 41 55 41 54 41 52 53 f6 47 38 40 4c 8b a0 88 0a 00 00 74 3d <41> 8b 4c 24 08 f6 c1 01 75 7c 49 8b 54 24 20 49 8b 44 24 18 48 89
[  961.870753] RSP: 0018:ffffbd9bc33dbaa8 EFLAGS: 00010202
[  961.870755] RAX: ffff9a8f72384500 RBX: ffffbd9bc33dbbf0 RCX: 0000000000000001
[  961.870756] RDX: ffffffff8fef34c8 RSI: 0000000000000041 RDI: ffffbd9bc33dbbf0
[  961.870757] RBP: ffffbd9bc33dbac8 R08: ffff9a8fbfd27080 R09: ffff9a8fb474c600
[  961.870759] R10: ffffbd9bc33dba98 R11: 00000000ffffffff R12: 0000000000000000
[  961.870760] R13: ffffbd9bc33dbbf0 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: 0000000000000002
[  961.870761] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9a8fbfd00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  961.870763] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  961.870764] CR2: 00007f0304ee3ddc CR3: 0000000050e0a002 CR4: 00000000000606e0
[  961.870765] Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!
```

Comment: Possibly not related with your issue, but since Linux kernel 4.14 (according to the your error log, you use 4.18 one) `filp_open` [natively works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53917617/3440745) with kernel-space paths; no needs to use `get_fs`/`set_fs` any more.

Comment: Opening files from kernel is a bad idea to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are correct that the crash is a result of `filp_open()` being called from the file "release" handler during process exit.

The direct cause of the crash seems to be due to `current->fs` being `NULL` when the `set_root()` function is called during the call to `filp_open()`.

The `do_exit()` function calls `exit_files()` to close the open files, but the files' "release" handlers are not called immediately.  Work items are queued on the current task in order to call the "release" handlers later.

The `do_exit()` function then calls `exit_fs()` which destroys `current->fs` and sets `current->fs` to `NULL`.

A bit further on, `do_exit()` calls `exit_task_work()` which will run the previously queued work items (and prevent any more work items being added). This results in the files' "release" handlers being called.

The upshot is that `current->fs` will be valid in the "release" handler when a file is closed normally, but `current->fs` will be `NULL` in the "release" handler when a file is closed on task exit.  `filp_open()` crashes when `current->fs` is `NULL`, so you should avoid calling it from a "release" handler, or at least check that `current->fs` is non-NULL before you call `filp_open()` from a "release" handler.

A possible work-around may be to call `filp_open()` from a kernel thread or call it via a work item queued on the system work queue by a call to `schedule_work()`.