# Equivalent of fprintf function in Linux Kernel Module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am developing a **Linux Kernel Module** and I need to use an equivalent of `fprintf` function to print some informations in a file.

I wonder if there is an equivalent of this function in kernel mode.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, `printk()`. It's used many many times all over the kernel code, I wonder how you couldn't have been stumbled across it yet

Comment: N.B.: [Read/write files within a Linux kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184274/read-write-files-within-a-linux-kernel-module), [Things You Never Should Do in the Kernel](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8110)

Comment: @Ctx I think that `printk` is equivalent for `printf` ( for just printing message on the console ). Does it used also as an equiavalent for `fprintf` ?

Comment: @gaston No, most messages from `printk()` do _not_ end up in the console (that would be a mess!) but is distributed to files according to the rules of the syslog daemon (i.e. most ends up in /var/log/kern.log)

Comment: @Ctx Yes you are right. However, FYI, `printk` does not work here.

Comment: You can print to a buffer first (e.g. using `snprintf` or `scnprintf`) and then write the buffer contents to a file.

Comment: @IanAbbott Which function I must use to write the buffer contents to a file kernel mode ?

Comment: @gaston Did you read the first post from my comment? There are some examples in it (depending on Linux kernel version).

Comment: @red0ct Yes I am reading it now thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't do that to begin with. If you need some information to be in the file, use DebugFS.