# Open and read files in kernel module

Tags: file, kernel, device-driver

I am currently working on a project which involves opening and reading a file from user space to take some data, but this has to be done from a device driver. I'm aware of why this shouldn't be done and have read of different methods to accomplish this, but they are not currently working in recent kernel versions, so I wonder if anyone knows how this could be done.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We are going to need a lot more details from you to be able to answer your question. Could you give us an outline of how you would do it? This should help us "fill the (potential) holes" in your approach and/or suggests better alternatives.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read/write files within a Linux kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184274/read-write-files-within-a-linux-kernel-module)