# How to get distro name and version from linux kernel code?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am looking if there is any API through which we can get OS distribution name and version from a Linux kernel module?

For example, I am using **SLES 12 service pack 4**. This information is present in */etc/os-release* file. I want to know if there is any way to get this information from kernel code.

```
linux:/ # cat /etc/os-release
NAME="SLES"
VERSION="12-SP4"
VERSION_ID="12.4"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP4"
ID="sles"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:12:sp4"
linux:/ #
```

Comment: No. Why do you need this to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no kernel API for detecting the current OS distribution, simply because it's not really needed. The Linux kernel itself is distribution-agnostic, and it couldn't care less which distribution is being run on top of it (having the kernel depend on what's being run on top of it wouldn't make much sense).

If you *really* want, you can open, read and parse the file yourself from kernel space. See more [in this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184274/read-write-files-within-a-linux-kernel-module) for an example, and in particular [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53917617/3889449) for modern kernels. In any case, remember that filesystem interaction from kernel space is generally discouraged, and could easily lead to bugs and compromise the security of the kernel if done wrong, so be careful.

If you are developing a kernel module, I would suggest you to parse the `/etc/os-release` file from userspace when compiling/installing the module and use a set of `#define`s, or even [module parameters](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x323.html). In any case, you should ask yourself *why* you need this information in kernel code in the first place, as you really shouldn't.