# How do I copy the contents of a file to another one in kernel space?

Tags: c, file, linux-kernel

I need to create a copy of a file with a different name in kernel space. I'm creating a new file with [`filp_open`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/include/linux/fs.h#L2527) (even though it's not really clear how I would specify the `O_CREAT` flag as it doesn't take flags, at least in the latest kernels) but I'm not really sure how to proceed once I have both this and the original file opened.

Should I simply use `kernel_read` and `kernel_write` on the descriptors? Or what else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1184274/3349425 may be of interest if you haven't seen it

Comment: Hmm.. `filp_open()` [**does** take `flags`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/fs/open.c#L1058).