# Use sys_open from kernel level

Tags: c, linux, file, linux-kernel, operating-system

Hi i am having some trouble using sys_open.At this point i am starting to think that i am doing something wrong with the arguments of the functions.
An example of how i use it:

```
fd = sys_open("file.txt" , O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0);
sys_write(fd, "test\n", strlen("test\n"));
sys_fsync(fd);
sys_fdatasync(fd);
sys_close(fd);
```

fd value is a non negative integer (0) .
Every single one of the functions returns 0 so i guess they are executed corectly.Except sys_write.
Every time that i go to find the file after i write on it i can never find it any idea maybe something on my code is wrong?

Comment: Meaning `sys_open` returns `fd = 0`?

Comment: yes it returns 0 if i remove O_CREAT it returns a negative but i have aother code that its creats a file using sys_creat

Comment: From the [open syscall description](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html): ```The mode argument specifies the file mode bits to be applied when a new file is created.  If neither O_CREAT nor O_TMPFILE is specified in flags, then mode is ignored (and can thus be specified as 0, or simply omitted).  The mode argument must be supplied if O_CREAT or O_TMPFILE is specified in flags; if it is not supplied, some arbitrary bytes from the stack will be applied as the file mode.```

Comment: i am sorry but i lost you so i use O_CREAT or O_TMPFILE i must give the 3rd argument?did i understand it coreclty?

Comment: Yes, if you do O_CREATE then you must supply a mode argument (argument 3) or else you'll get undefined behavior. Also typically file descriptor `fd` 0 is for stdin, so getting 0 from sys_open on a file is a bad sign. Read that link I posted and update your mode bit argument. If it answers your question, let me know and I can post it as an answer

Comment: yes i am trying to use the the mode_t i will let you know if that fix it thank you

Comment: well after reading the link you sent me it was helpful so thank you but unfortunetly it didnt resolve my problem if you have any idea why it returns fd =0 or what should i look for please le me know thanks again :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231861/discussion-between-wxz-and-mast-reyheart).

Comment: The string `"file.txt"` is not in user space

Comment: what do you mean isnt in user space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sys_` family of functions for Linux are considered [deprecated now](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/syscalls.h#L1069). However, for the purposes of this question, `sys_open` is a user-level function that calls the `open` syscall, which then calls the kernel level `do_sys_open()`, the latter two defined in `fs/open.c`. So to open files from within the kernel you should stick to kernel level functions and not user-level functions.

[Here are some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1184274/13020139) about opening files at the kernel level, some of which are deprecated as well, so be aware.