# Not able to see file generated using filp_open

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Trying a file creation under /tmp like below:

```
struct file *fp;
fp = file_open("/tmp/sample-logfile",O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC, 0666);
if (IS_ERR(fp))
printk("<0>Create record file error!\n\r");
file_close(fp);
```

After the kernel comes-up, there is no file visible. There are no errors also shown during kernel bootup.
Now sure what is going wrong here?

My file_open is like this:

```
struct file *file_open(const char *path, int flags, int rights) 
{
    struct file *filp = NULL;
    mm_segment_t oldfs;
    int err = 0;

    oldfs = get_fs();
    set_fs(get_ds());
    filp = filp_open(path, flags, rights);
    set_fs(oldfs);
    if (IS_ERR(filp)) {
        err = PTR_ERR(filp);
        return NULL;
    }
    return filp;
}
```

Comment: Did you follow a tutorial for kernel programming? Add links to your question. The use of `IS_ERR` in combination with your `return NULL` looks suspicious. AFAIK `IS_ERR` or `IS_ERR_VALUE` does not cover `NULL`.

Comment: Which kernel **version** do you use? Modern Linux kernel doesn't require `get_fs`/`set_fs` for use files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53917617/3440745

Comment: How do you know your code is called?

Comment: @Bodo Indeed, `IS_ERR(NULL)` is false. There is `IS_ERR_OR_NULL(ptr)` which returns `ptr==NULL || IS_ERR(ptr)`.

Comment: ASIDE: `printk("<0>Create record file error!\n\r");` should be `printk(KERN_EMERG "Create record file error!\n");`. Do not put `\r` on the end!

Comment: You could add this to your `file_open` function before returning `NULL` to see the error number in the kernel log (since you decided not to pass the error number back to the caller): `printk(KERN_ERR "failed to open '%s' - err %d\n", path, err);`.