# how to acess and change variable of kernel space from user space

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

i,

I have posted query previously and i am repeating same I want to modify igmpv3 (Linux) 
which is  inbuilt in kernel2.6.-- such that it reads a value from a file and appropriately decides reserved(res 1) value inside the igmpv3 paket which is sent by a host.

I want to add more to above question by saying that this is more a generic question of changing variable
of kernel space from user space.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,

Bhavin

Answer (score 2):

From the perspective of a user land program, you should think of the driver as a "black box" with well defined interfaces instead of code with variables you can change. Using this mental model, there are four ways (i.e. interfaces) to communicate control information to the driver that you should consider:

- Command line options. You can pass parameters to a kernel module which are then available to it during initialization.
- IOCTLs. This is the traditional way of passing control information to a driver, but this mechanism is a little more cumbersome to use than `sysfs`.
- `proc` the process information pseudo-file system. `proc` creates files in the `/proc` directory which user land programs can read and sometimes write. In the past, this interface was appropriated to also communicate with drivers. Although `proc` looks similarly to `sysfs`, newer drivers (Linux 2.6) should use `sysfs` instead as the intent of the `proc` is to report on the status of processes.
- `sysfs` is a pseudo-file system used to export information about drivers and devices. See the documentation in the kernel ([Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt)) for more details and code samples. For your particular case, pay attention to the "store" method.

Depending on when you need to communicate with the driver (i.e. initialization or run time), you should add either a new command line option or a new `sysfs` entry to change how the driver treats the value of reserved fields in the packet.

With regard to `filp_open`, the function's comment is

```
/**
 * This is the helper to open a file from kernelspace if you really
 * have to.  But in generally you should not do this, so please move
 * along, nothing to see here..
 */
```

meaning there are better ways than this to do what you want. Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275386/file-i-o-in-a-linux-kernel-module) for more information on why drivers generally should not open files.

Answer (score 1):

You normally can't. Only structures exposed in `/proc` and `/sys` or via a module parameter can be modified from userspace.

Comment: what if we use filp_open, get_fs() and set_fs() in the igmpv3 file of kernel and compile the linux.