# device_create with existing device name

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I'm learning how to write character device drivers as dynamically-loadable modules for the Linux. Typically I use the following sequence of function calls to register the device and create a device file which appears under `/dev/`:

```
alloc_chrdev_region(&first, 0, 1, "myclass");
myclass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "myclass");
device_create(myclass, NULL, first, NULL, "mydevicefile");
cdev_init(&c_dev, &fops);
cdev_add(&c_dev, first, 1);
```

The device file then appears at `/dev/mydevicefile` and I'm able to interact with it.

This made me wonder what would happen if passed an existing device file name instead of *"mydevicefile"*:

```
device_create(myclass, NULL, first, NULL, "null");
```

This resulted in `/dev/null` being replaced by my character device file -- and more concerning: an onslaught of error messages in my console from daemons expecting the original `/dev/null`. Not even removing my faux `null` module fixed this.

While in practice there should not be an existing device file with the same name as the one my module uses, the fact that it is theoretically possible to overwrite another device file still bothers me.

How do I protect against the case that a device file already exists with the same name as the one I intend to use?

**UPDATE**: I suppose what I'm really tying to find out is why udev is permitting the replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Device node creation is typically left to be handled by user space operations. This is the purpose of `udev`: to populate and handle the user space `/dev/` directory by interpreting the data from `sysfm`.

The name passed to the `device_create` function is merely a suggested default name that appears in `sysfm` along with other data about the device; it's ultimately up to the user space utility or user to decide what to do with that data.

It just happens that the default behavior of `udev` when it encounters a device with the same name is to overwrite the old device node with the new device node: http://marc.info/?l=linux-hotplug&m=125559736630729

Answer (score 2):

All the device drivers (found in `/dev`) are basically file types, this means the way you check to see if a device file already exists, is the same way you check to see if *any* file exists. One way would be to use:

```
#include <unistd.h>  // for F_OK and access()

...

if( access( "/dev/null", F_OK ) != -1 ) {
    printf("File already exists!\n");
} else {
    printf("File doesn't exist!\n");
    // create new dev here
}
```

Since `/dev/null` *does* exist, you'll see "File exists!" here

Comment: When I try to use `access` within my module, gcc spits out: `error: implicit declaration of function 'access'`. I have `#include <linux/unistd.h>` so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Turns out that accessing userspace files from within the kernel is generally bad practice: http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/WhyWritingFilesFromKernelIsBad

Comment: @VilhelmGray - Yeah, sorry about that, I was thinking about checking form userspace if the /dev/ existed. Check out the link in the accepted answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275386/file-i-o-in-a-linux-kernel-module it is possible to access the file system from the kernel and then do what `access()` does, or even try to `open()` a particular /dev to check for the existance of it... there should be  abetter way, but I need to think on it for a bit

Comment: Perhaps the best practice would be to just register the device in the kernel, then implement a userland init script which would check if there are any filename conflicts before executing mknod to create the device node. But then again, it makes me wonder why udev wouldn't perform such a basic check in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
This resulted in /dev/null being replaced by my character device file
```

You can create a new NULL device file using the mknod utility

> sudo mknod -m 0666 /dev/null c 1 3