# Linux filp_open error number definitions

Tags: linux

I have a question about the `filp_open` function:

I can get the error number from the `IS_ERR` function but I do not understand the meaning of the error number.

Where can find the `filp_open` error number definitions?

Comment: `man errno` is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 5):

You should not use `filp_open` to read/write files in kernel mode. For (obvious) security reasons. Other reasons can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184274/how-to-read-write-files-within-a-linux-kernel-module) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275386/file-i-o-in-a-linux-kernel-module) (taken from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858801/file-copy-using-filp-open#comment36721536_23858801)). The [official documentation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/open.c?v=3.15#L913) also recomends not to use `flp_open`:

> This is the helper to open a file from kernelspace if you really have to.  But in generally you should not do this, so please move along, nothing to see here..

#### Error code definitions

The kernel uses the same error numbers (errno) in kernel space as in the user space. So, as [OmnipotentEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518061/linux-filp-open-error-number-define#comment39837401_25518061) pointed out, you can see `man errno` for a reference on what the errors generally mean.

It is also helpful to have a look at the actual implementation of [`filp_open`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/open.c?v=3.15#L936) and its possible error sources, such as [`file_open_name`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/open.c?v=3.15#L918) and [`build_open_flags`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/open.c?v=3.15#L839).

Note that `IS_ERR` does *not* return the error but merely returns whether the supplied pointer is an error value or not. You have to use `PTR_ERR` to retrieve the error value from the pointer in case `IS_ERR` is true. Example:

```
fptr = filp_open(...)

if (IS_ERR(fptr)) {
    printk("%d\n", PTR_ERR(fptr));
}
```

Comment: Btw, should be PTR_ERR() instead of ERR_PTR().