# how to write logs to specific file from kernel space?

Tags: logging, linux-kernel, kernel-module, rsyslog, printk

I have a kernel module that uses printk() for debugging. printk() logs to /var/log/messages. /var/log/messages contains information of other modules too. I am trying to implement dynamic tracing for my module. My plan is to use ioctl calls to set different logging/tracing level and then, log the information from the module to a different path (my_module.log).

I am not getting information on how to write logs from kernel space (inside kernel module) to a specific file? I have checked for rsyslog but couldn't find any information if this can be used inside a kernel module.

I see a similar question, but it is not helping.
[Linux kernel : logging to a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719930/linux-kernel-logging-to-a-specific-file)

Could you suggest any leads?

Comment: printk does not write to a file. It writes to a buffer. klogd reads the buffer and sends it to syslog. Your syslog configuration decides where kernel messages go.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction @stark. I am looking for a way to log from a specific kernel modules to a different file (like /var/log/my_module.log). Can you suggest some leads? In syslog, I don't find anything related that allows logs from specific module to a different file.

Comment: Most kernel prints are prefixed with the function name. syslog supports filtering.