# Linux kernel_write function returns EFBIG when appending data to big file

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, systems-programming

The task is to write simple character device that copies all the data written to the device to tmp a file.

I use `kernel_write` function to write data to file and its work fine most of the cases. But when the output file size is bigger than 2.1 GB, `kernel_write` function fails with return value -27.

To write to file I use this function:

```c
void writeToFile(void* buf, size_t size, loff_t *offset) {
    struct file* destFile;
    char* filePath = "/tmp/output";
    destFile = filp_open(filePath,  O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_APPEND, 0666);
    if (IS_ERR(destFile) || destFile == NULL) {
      printk("Cannot open destination file");
      return;
    }
    size_t res = kernel_write(destFile, buf, size, offset);
    printk("%ld", res);
    filp_close(destFile, NULL);
}
```

If the size of "/tmp/output" < 2.1 GB, this function works just fine.

If the size of "/tmp/output"> 2.1 GB, `kernel_write` starts to return `-27`.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Nope. 
I create big (2.1 GB) /tmp/output file manually.  Then try to append small data (2 bytes) to it through driver. And kernel_write again returns -27.

Comment: Try moving the output file to a different path outside of `/tmp`; any different results from `kernel_write`?

Comment: 27 is EFBIG, "File too large"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable [Large File Support](https://users.suse.com/%7Eaj/linux_lfs.html) (LFS) with the `O_LARGEFILE` flag.

The below code worked for me. Sorry, I made some other changes for debugging, but I commented above the relevant line.

```c
struct file* writeToFile(void* buf, size_t size, loff_t *offset) 
{
    struct file* destFile;
    char* filePath = "/tmp/output";
    size_t res;
    
    // Add the O_LARGEFILE flag here
    destFile = filp_open(filePath, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_LARGEFILE, 0666);
    if (IS_ERR(destFile)) 
    {
        printk("Error in opening: <%ld>", (long)destFile);
        return destFile;
    }
    if (destFile == NULL)
    {
        printk("Error in opening: null");
        return destFile;
    }
    
    res = kernel_write(destFile, buf, size, offset);
    printk("CODE: <%ld>", res);
    filp_close(destFile, NULL);

    return destFile;
}
```

To test it, I created a file with `fallocate -l 3G /tmp/output`, then removed the `O_CREAT` flag because it was giving the kernel permission errors.

---

I should add a disclaimer that a lot of folks says that File I/O from the kernel is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/275431/4294399). Even while testing this out on my own, I accidentally crashed my computer twice due to dumb errors.

Maybe do this instead: [Read/Write from `/proc` File](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/Linux_Kernel_Module_Programming_Guide/x773.html)